# What's the most cost-effective transit pass for the Basel area (including RVL)?

Tags: germany, switzerland, basel

In the Basel area one can buy a TriRegion Mini pass for €9.10 which covers some of Basel as well as the RVL zones 1, 2, 3, and 8 in Germany.  I'm looking for a transit pass I can buy that would be good for at least a couple of weeks and would cover a similar or larger area, e.g. as far as Pratteln, Rheinfelden, and perhaps also Kaiseraugst.

A group pass might be worth considering, as I'd be taking two kids along, one of whom is elementary school age, and the other of whom is 15 (and thus considered an adult, at least by Deutsche Bahn).

Is there a longer-term pass for Basel that can cover these conditions?

Comment: Have you looked at https://rvl-online.de/tickets-tarife/nach-fahrscheinen/monatskarten/?

Comment: Beyond that, more details on your expected travel patterns and priorities (peace of mind/convenience vs. price) might be useful. I don't expect that you will find a cheap all-inclusive multi-week ticket so you might have to look into combining several things (monthly ticket for some part of the area plus individual tickets to go elsewhere, etc.)

Comment: @Relaxed Yeah, the RegioCard Plus or RegioCard Plus Light might be a possibility, except that it only lets you take kids with you on weekends or holidays.  A lot of these long-term deals seem to add restrictions like that that make them not such good deals as they first appear.

Comment: You can get a TNW - it includes the area around Basel in Switzerland, but not much else.